# How to make the input text area bigger on tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on a SMS text app and im made a simple GUI with tkinter.
It has 3 fields to enter data and two buttons.

1. Sender
2. Receiver
3. Message

What I'm trying to do is make the Message text input way bigger than the rest so the user has more space to write the message (not huge).

This is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def send_message():
    print('sent')

def clear_text():
    print('cleared')

#window object
app = Tk()
# Sender
Sender_text = StringVar()
Sender_label = Label(app, text='Sender', font=('bold', 14), pady=20)
Sender_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Sender_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Sender_text)
Sender_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
# Receiver
Receiver_text = StringVar()
Receiver_label = Label(app, text='Receiver', font=('bold', 14))
Receiver_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
Receiver_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Receiver_text)
Receiver_entry.grid(row=0, column=3)
# Message
Message_text = StringVar()
Message_label = Label(app, text='Message', font=('bold', 14))
Message_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
Message_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Message_text)
Message_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
# Buttons
send_btn = Button(app, text='Send', width=12, command=send_message)
send_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)
clear_btn = Button(app, text='Clear', width=12, command=clear_text)
clear_btn.grid(row=2, column=1)


app.title('SMS')
app.geometry('430x145')

#start
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Message_entry = Text(app)`.....

Comment: I tried switching from Message_entry = Entry(app) to Message_entry = TexT(app) but it doesnt seem to work. My syntax is really bad.

Comment: You can make the text bigger by specifying `font` and `width` options: `Message_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Message_text, font=('bold', 20), width=30)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Text() instead of Entry(). Text() size is easy to change.

```py
from tkinter import *

def send_message():
    print('sent')

def clear_text():
    print('cleared')

#window object
app = Tk()
# Sender
Sender_text = StringVar()
Sender_label = Label(app, text='Sender', font=('bold', 14), pady=20)
Sender_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Sender_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Sender_text)
Sender_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
# Receiver
Receiver_text = StringVar()
Receiver_label = Label(app, text='Receiver', font=('bold', 14))
Receiver_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
Receiver_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Receiver_text)
Receiver_entry.grid(row=0, column=3)
# Message
Message_text = StringVar()
Message_label = Label(app, text='Message', font=('bold', 14))
Message_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
#Message_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=Message_text)
Message_entry = Text(app, width=20, height=2, font=("Bold",20))
Message_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
# Buttons
send_btn = Button(app, text='Send', width=12, command=send_message)
send_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)
clear_btn = Button(app, text='Clear', width=12, command=clear_text)
clear_btn.grid(row=2, column=1)


app.title('SMS')
app.geometry('430x145')

#start
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This made the text bigger but not the input box bigger :(

Comment: The actual box can be changed with width and height. "Height = 2" is double the font size.